# Bash: renaming files based on their names

Tags: bash

(Bash newb here; my apologies.)

I have a folder of a couple hundred files like

```
"Cool Stuff - Some Movie Series #14.mp4"
"Other Stuff - Some Movie Series #49.mp4"
"Further Stuff - Some Movie Series #48.mp4"
```

and so on.

I'd like to mass rename them to be, respectively

```
"14 Cool Stuff - Some Movie Series.mp4"
"49 Other Stuff - Some Movie Series.mp4"
"48 Further Stuff - Some Movie Series.mp4"
```

and so on.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

(One solution that may or may not be promising is to use `rename`. For example, `rename 's/Movie/Mxvxx/g' *` would replace the vowels with `x`s. But what I'm unable to do with that strategy is assign the numbers that come between the `#` and the `.mp4` to a variable that I then prepend to the filename. So I fear that `rename` is a misguided strategy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the quotation marks are not part of the filename.

```
prename -n 's/(.*) #(.*)\.mp4/$2 $1.mp4/' *.mp4
```

Output:

```
Cool Stuff - Some Movie Series #14.mp4 renamed as 14 Cool Stuff - Some Movie Series.mp4
Further Stuff - Some Movie Series #48.mp4 renamed as 48 Further Stuff - Some Movie Series.mp4
Other Stuff - Some Movie Series #49.mp4 renamed as 49 Other Stuff - Some Movie Series.mp4
```

If output looks okay, remove `-n`.